# Java - how to extract the value of fields from another class

Tags: java

I am trying to get all the fields and values from another read-only class, and write them into a file, how to get the values of fields?

The class is read-only, and don't have getters:

```java
  public class colorConstants {
    public static final String BLUE = "blue";
    public static final String RED = "red";
    public static final String YELLOW = "yellow";
    ...
    
    public colorConstants() {}
  }
```

In another class:

```java
Field[] fields = colorConstants.class.getFields();
for(Field : fields) {
  String fieldName = fieldName;
  
  //how to get the value of each field
  String value = fieldName.get()?
}
```

Comment: you can only get the value of static fields from a class. You can pass `null` into `get` for static members

Comment: You can't change the constants class? Because it sounds like you really want it to be an `enum`.

Comment: @JohnBayko no I can't change it, it is imported from other people's package

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import static java.lang.reflect.Modifier.STATIC;

public class Example {
    public static class colorConstants {
        public static final String BLUE = "blue";
        public static final String RED = "red";
        public static final String YELLOW = "yellow";
        public String blah;

        public colorConstants() {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fields = colorConstants.class.getFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {

            if ((field.getModifiers() & STATIC) != 0) {
                String value = (String) field.get(null);
                System.out.println(value);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ignoring non-static field " + field.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've improved the style by changing `colorConstants` to `ColorConstants`, as class names should start with upper case letters, and changing `Field` to `field`.

Comment: this could throw exceptions if there are non-static members. Better to check `field.Modifiers & Modifier.STATIC != 0` before attempting

Comment: Thank you for your answer. modified the question that the colorConstants class is read-only and doesn't have getters, so the field.get() will have illegal access exception.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The class and fields are `public`. Please add the stack trace of the exception to your question.